# Django restframe work send email from posted data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework, I have a contact us table.. in views, I use class based view i want to send email when user post data .. this's my function

```
   def post(self, request):  
        return self.create(request)
        return send_email(request)

def send_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
        message = request.POST.get('message', '')
        from_email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['haguwanax@l0real.net'], fail_silently=False)
        return Response (status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

it saves the data but there's nothing being sent.
this's my settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Where is `send_mail` function?

Comment: Why don't you use EMAIL_HOST_USER instead of from_email ?

Comment: if i have a send_email function .. how can i reference it in the post function ?

Comment: I updated the code.. plz check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use two return at a time in a same block of code. Your second return statement will not execute.

I don't think your create method need return something. It's just storing some values. 
And your send email might return true or false if email send is successful or not
Please use only one return statement in your post function.

You can rewrite the code following:

```
 def post(self, request):  
      self.create(request)
      check_mail=send_email(request)
      if check_mail:
           return Response (status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def send_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
        message = request.POST.get('message', '')
        from_email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['haguwanax@l0real.net'], 
        fail_silently=False)
        return True
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. I don't know why but when I print (request.POST) it returns an empty list

Answer (score 0):

The `send_email` function is not being called because you're calling it after `return self.create(request)`. Your code for `send_email` is hence unreachable.

Please use only one `return` statement in your `post` function.

You can call email method without the `return` statement and then call `return self.create(request)`

`send_email(request)
return self.create(request)`

Comment: I tried to put ` return send_email(request)` alone and nothing happened

Comment: I've edited the answer. Make sure you're using CreateAPIView for create to work. Also, you can check if the correct args are being passed to the email function by using pdb.